# Общая цена всех покупок аккумулируется в "Итоговой цене" в первой карточке. А должно быть: каждый итог - в своей Карточке

Tags: javascript, ооп

Есть две карточки товара. Каждая карточка внутри содержит несколько checkbox'ов (для выбора опций товара, которые увеличивают ценник и добавляют бонусы покупателю за выбор опций).

Внизу каждой карточки товара есть своя мини-корзина, куда прилетает цена с учетом выбранных опций.

Проблема:
Выбираю оба товара + чекаю опции, но в итоге  цена за ОБА товара показывается только в первой карточке (мини-корзина во второй карточке - молчит).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
'use strict';

//№2. КЛАСС, в нем есть КОНСТРУКТОР (шаблон cо свойствами): start
class ProductList {

constructor (samboFormaDiv = '.samboForma',      //сюда залетает КарточкаТовара
myCheck = 'input[type="checkbox"]', //чекбокс
calcPrice =  '.calc_price',   //сюда залетает Цена (+опции)товара 
calcBonus =  '.calc_bonus'  //сюда залетают Бонусы
)
{
      this.samboFormaDiv = samboFormaDiv;//в тег 'samboForma' залетает КарточкаТовара
      this.goods = [] ; //тут храню сырые данные из API(?)
      this.productObjects = [] ;//Важн.раб.св-во: тут храню экземпляры КЛАССОВ(?)

      this.myCheck = myCheck;
      this.calcPrice = calcPrice ;
      this.calcBonus = calcBonus ;



// указал на наличие методов (функции)
this.fetсhGoodsData(); // метод "Получить Массив Данных из API"(?).Пока вручную внесим
this.render(); // отрисовка (?)
this.calcPriceBonus ();// д/з №3 урок2_ расчет 

   }


fetсhGoodsData() {
//2.1. этот массив будто получен из api(?) // фактич.ввел руками тут
  this.goods = [
  {
  title:     'Детская форма Самбо',
  id:        '1',
  img:       'sambo1.jpg',
  topPrice:   1000,
  topBonus:   50,
  clubPrice:  100,
  clubBonus:  25,
  samboPrice: 50,
  samboBonus: 20,
  namePrice:  20,
  nameBonus:  10,
  blackPrice: 10,
  blackBonus: 5,
  hakiPrice:  5,
  hakiBonus:  0
  },

  {
  title:     'Форма Самбо ',
  id:        '2',
  img:       'sambo2.jpg',
  topPrice:   2000,
  topBonus:   50,
  clubPrice:  100,
  clubBonus:  25,
  samboPrice: 50,
  samboBonus: 20,
  namePrice:  20,
  nameBonus:  10,
  blackPrice: 10,
  blackBonus: 5,
  hakiPrice:  5,
  hakiBonus:  0
  },
  ]

}

//2.2. метод: внутрь <samboForma> д.залетать 2 карточки samboForma_cart
render( ) {
// ссылка на тег <div class="samboForma">
const samboFormaDiv = document.querySelector (this.samboFormaDiv);

// FOR ( OF ): перебор данных Сырого массива ("получен" из API) (?)
for (let i of this.goods) {

 // новый экзмепляр (ОднаКарточкаТовара), где родитель class ProductItem
 const oneProductCard = new FormaSambo(i);

// В пустой массив 'productObjects'  - добавляю данные в конец [ ]" !!
 this.productObjects.push(oneProductCard);

  //вставка <div class="samboForma"> __тут КарточкаТовара___ </div>
  //html-код КарточкиТовара тянется из class FormaSambo
  //getHTMLString() - метод из class FormaSambo
  samboFormaDiv.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', oneProductCard.getHTMLString());

    }

  }

calcPriceBonus (){
const myCheck = document.querySelectorAll (this.myCheck) ;
const calcPrice = document.querySelector (this.calcPrice);
const calcBonus = document.querySelector (this.calcBonus);
  myCheck.forEach (function (e){

  e.addEventListener ('change' , function(e){
   

let sumPrice = 0; 
let sumBonus = 0;
if (e.target.checked == true){
 sumPrice = e.target.dataset.price;
 sumBonus = e.target.dataset.bonus;
} else {
 sumPrice = -(e.target.dataset.price);
 sumBonus = -(e.target.dataset.bonus);
}

 calcPrice.textContent = +calcPrice.textContent + +sumPrice;
 calcBonus.innerHTML = +calcBonus.innerHTML + +sumBonus;
 
  })

 })
} 


 }
//№2. КЛАСС, в нем есть КОНСТРУКТОР (шаблон cо свойствами): end




// №1. Класс ФормаСАМБО (карточкаТовара?) :start
class FormaSambo {
  constructor ( product   ) {
  //заголовок Карточки
   this.title = product.title || 'no_name'; // Детская , Взрослая
   this.topPrice = product.topPrice || '0'; // 1000 , 2000
   this.topBonus = product.topBonus || '0'; // 50, 100
   this.id = product.id;
   this.img = product?.img || 'no_foto.jpg';

   //вышивка (эмблема клуба)
   this.clubPrice = product.clubPrice  || '0'; // 100
   this.clubBonus = product.clubBonus || '0'; // 25

   //вышивка (эмблема самбо)
   this.samboPrice = product.samboPrice  || '0'; // 50
   this.samboBonus = product.samboBonus || '0'; // 20
       
   //вышивка (имя борца)
   this.namePrice = product.namePrice  || '0'; // 20
   this.nameBonus = product.nameBonus || '0'; // 10

   //цвет формы (черный)
   this.blackPrice = product.blackPrice  || '0'; // 10
   this.blackBonus = product.blackBonus || '0'; // 5

    //цвет формы (хаки)
   this.hakiPrice = product.hakiPrice  || '0'; // 5
   this.hakiBonus = product.hakiBonus || '0'; // 0

   }

  //отрисовка Карточек samboForma_cart "дет/взросл форма": start
  getHTMLString ( ){ return `
  <div class="samboForma_cart">

    <div class="forma_kid_name">
    <p class="name_text">${this.title}</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="formaSambo" id="${this.id}" data-price=" ${this.topPrice}" data-bonus=" ${this.topBonus}" >
    </div>
    
    <img class="forma_img" src="./img/${this.img}" alt="" >

    <div class="priceBonus">
    <p class="forma_price"> Цена: ${this.topPrice} руб*</p>
    <p class="forma_bonus"> Бонус: ${this.topBonus} баллов*</p>    
    </div>

    <!-- Блок ВЫШИВКА: start -->
    <div class="embroidery">
    <div class="embr_top optionString">Вышивка на форме</div>

    <div class="embr">
    <p class="embr_top">Эмблема клуба:</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="formaSambo" id="embr_club" data-price=" ${this.clubPrice}" data-bonus=" ${this.clubBonus}" >
    </div>

    <div class="priceBonus">
    <p class="forma_price"> Цена: ${this.clubPrice} руб*</p>
    <p class="forma_bonus"> Бонус: ${this.clubBonus} баллов*</p>
    </div>

    <div class="embr">
    <p class="embr_top">Эмблема САМБО:</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="formaSambo" id="embr_sambo" data-price="${this.samboPrice} " data-bonus=" ${this.samboBonus} " >
    </div>

    <div class="priceBonus">
    <p class="forma_price"> Цена: ${this.samboPrice} руб*</p>
    <p class="forma_bonus"> Бонус: ${this.samboBonus} баллов*</p>
    </div>

    <div class="embr">
    <p class="embr_top">Имя Фамилия:</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="formaSambo" id="embr_fio" data-price="${this.namePrice} " data-bonus=" ${this.nameBonus}" >
    </div>

    <div class="priceBonus">
    <p class="forma_price"> Цена: ${this.namePrice} руб*</p>
    <p class="forma_bonus"> Бонус: ${this.nameBonus} баллов*</p>
    </div>
    
    </div>
    <!-- Блок ВЫШИВКА: end-->


<!-- Блок ЦВЕТ ФОРМЫ: start-->
<div class="forma_color">
 <div class="color_top optionString">Опция: цвет формы</div>

    <div class="clr">
    <p class="color_top">Цвет формы Черный</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="formaSambo" id="clr_black" data-price=" ${this.blackPrice}" data-bonus="${this.blackBonus} " >
    </div>

    <div class="priceBonus">
    <p class="forma_price"> Цена: ${this.blackPrice} руб*</p>
    <p class="forma_bonus"> Бонус: ${this.blackBonus} баллов*</p>
    </div>

    <div class="clr">
    <p class="color_top">Цвет формы Хаки:</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="formaSambo" id="clr_haki" data-price=" ${this.hakiPrice}" data-bonus="${this.hakiBonus} " >
    </div>

    <div class="priceBonus">
    <p class="forma_price"> Цена: ${this.hakiPrice} руб*</p>
    <p class="forma_bonus"> Бонус: ${this.hakiBonus} баллов*</p>
    </div> 

</div>
<!-- Блок ЦВЕТ ФОРМЫ: end-->
    
    <!-- Цена за 1 покупку: start -->
    <div class="calc">

    <div class="calc_text">Итого: Стоимость и Бонусы</div>
    <p class="calc_price"></p>
    <div class="calc_bonus"></div>

    </div>
    <!-- Цена за 1 покупку: end -->


    </div>
  `
  
  }
  //отрисовка Карточек samboForma_cart "дет/взросл форма": end


}
// №1. Класс ФормаСАМБО (карточкаТовара?) :end

// скрипт стартует отсюда
const catalog = new ProductList(  );
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/*фон */

.wrapper {
  background-color: #5e5d5d;
  min-height: 100vh;
}


/*шапка: лого и "Корзина"*/

.header_top {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: rgb(149, 149, 149);
  height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


/* позиция лого: поверх*/

.header_logo {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 30px;
}


/*_____ Кнопка 'Корзина' _____*/

.btn-cart {
  margin-right: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 35px;
  align-self: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
}


/*эфф-т при наведении на кнопку*/

.btn-cart:hover {
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 13px 4px #d1d1d1;
}


/*Общая обертка: samboForma ( grid )*/

.samboForma {
  max-width: 1200px;
  /* border: 1px solid #000; */
  margin: 35px auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 22px;
  /*адаптация grid под размер окна браузера*/
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 450px));
  justify-content: center;
}


/*==== КАРТОЧКА ТОВАРА ====*/


/*Обертка Одной карточки товара*/

.samboForma_cart {
  max-width: 450px;
  border: 1px solid #2a2828;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.forma_kid_name {
  margin: 15px 0 15px 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.name_text {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
}


/*checkbox: УВЕЛИЧИТЬ окошко*/

input[type=checkbox] {
  align-self: center;
  transform: scale(1.8);
  opacity: 0.9;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*центровка фото через vw !*/

.forma_img {
  margin: 0 15%;
}


/*ценник и бонус*/

.priceBonus {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 15px 30px 15px 30px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #bfbfbf;
}


/*Блок "вышивка" (embroidery)*/

.embroidery {
  margin: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  row-gap: 8px;
}

.embr_top {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.embr {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-right: 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
}


/*Блок "цвето формы" )*/

.forma_color {
  margin: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  row-gap: 8px;
}

.color_top {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.clr {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-right: 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
}


/*цвет слов "Вышивка", "Цвет формы"*/

.optionString {
  color: #e20724;
}


/* === Блок Цена за 1 покупку ===*/

.calc {
  border: 1px solid #797979;
  margin: 0 25px 25px 25px;
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 15px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #fffec2;
}

.calc_text {
  font-weight: 600;
}


/*Приписка слов ДО и ПОСЛЕ*/

.calc_price::before {
  content: 'Цена покупки: ';
}

.calc_price::after {
  content: ' рублей ';
}

.calc_bonus::before {
  content: 'Вами заработано: ';
}

.calc_bonus::after {
  content: ' бонусов ';
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styleForma.css">
  <title>СпортФорма</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header class="header_top">
      <div class="header_logo">
        <img class="bearLogo" src="img/logo.png" alt="">
      </div>

      <button class="btn-cart" type="button">Корзина</button>
    </header>

    <main>
      <!-- samboForma (на grid): start -->
      <!-- внутрь <samboForma> д.залетать 2 карточки samboForma_cart-->
      <div class="samboForma">




      </div>
      <!-- samboForma (на grid): end -->


    </main>

  </div>

  <script src="js/samboForma.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Проблема возникает из-за не правильной работы с селекторами, если Вы нажмете чекбокс на второй карточке то сумма появится в первой, т.е. она находит первые попавшиеся поля для суммы, а должно искать внутри карточки для этого можно использовать что-то типа `карточка.querySelector(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С учетом того что рефакторинг кода не входит в мою задачу, а он тут явно необходим, я поправил функцию чтобы код работал, главным образом я ввел индексы для сумм и бонусов а так же расчет самого индекса (исходя из чекбокса)

```
    const COUNT_CART_CHECKBOXES = 6
    const i =  Math.floor(index / COUNT_CART_CHECKBOXES)
    calcPrice[i].textContent = +calcPrice[i].textContent + +sumPrice;
    calcBonus[i].innerHTML = +calcBonus[i].innerHTML + +sumBonus;
```

вот код функции целиком:

```
calcPriceBonus (){
const myCheck = document.querySelectorAll (this.myCheck) ;
const calcPrice = document.querySelectorAll (this.calcPrice);
const calcBonus = document.querySelectorAll (this.calcBonus);
const COUNT_CART_CHECKBOXES = 6

  myCheck.forEach (function (e, index){
    e.addEventListener ('change' , function(e){
      let sumPrice = 0; 
      let sumBonus = 0;

      if (e.target.checked == true){
        sumPrice = e.target.dataset.price;
        sumBonus = e.target.dataset.bonus;
      } else {
        sumPrice = -(e.target.dataset.price);
        sumBonus = -(e.target.dataset.bonus);
      }
          
      const i =  Math.floor(index / COUNT_CART_CHECKBOXES)
      calcPrice[i].textContent = +calcPrice[i].textContent + +sumPrice;
      calcBonus[i].innerHTML = +calcBonus[i].innerHTML + +sumBonus;
    })
  })
}
```

вот исправленный вариант снипета

```js
'use strict';

//№2. КЛАСС, в нем есть КОНСТРУКТОР (шаблон cо свойствами): start
class ProductList {

constructor (samboFormaDiv = '.samboForma',      //сюда залетает КарточкаТовара
myCheck = 'input[type="checkbox"]', //чекбокс
calcPrice =  '.calc_price',   //сюда залетает Цена (+опции)товара 
calcBonus =  '.calc_bonus'  //сюда залетают Бонусы
)
{
      this.samboFormaDiv = samboFormaDiv;//в тег 'samboForma' залетает КарточкаТовара
      this.goods = [] ; //тут храню сырые данные из API(?)
      this.productObjects = [] ;//Важн.раб.св-во: тут храню экземпляры КЛАССОВ(?)

      this.myCheck = myCheck;
      this.calcPrice = calcPrice ;
      this.calcBonus = calcBonus ;



// указал на наличие методов (функции)
this.fetсhGoodsData(); // метод "Получить Массив Данных из API"(?).Пока вручную внесим
this.render(); // отрисовка (?)
this.calcPriceBonus ();// д/з №3 урок2_ расчет 

   }


fetсhGoodsData() {
//2.1. этот массив будто получен из api(?) // фактич.ввел руками тут
  this.goods = [
  {
  title:     'Детская форма Самбо',
  id:        '1',
  img:       'sambo1.jpg',
  topPrice:   1000,
  topBonus:   50,
  clubPrice:  100,
  clubBonus:  25,
  samboPrice: 50,
  samboBonus: 20,
  namePrice:  20,
  nameBonus:  10,
  blackPrice: 10,
  blackBonus: 5,
  hakiPrice:  5,
  hakiBonus:  0
  },

  {
  title:     'Форма Самбо ',
  id:        '2',
  img:       'sambo2.jpg',
  topPrice:   2000,
  topBonus:   50,
  clubPrice:  100,
  clubBonus:  25,
  samboPrice: 50,
  samboBonus: 20,
  namePrice:  20,
  nameBonus:  10,
  blackPrice: 10,
  blackBonus: 5,
  hakiPrice:  5,
  hakiBonus:  0
  },
  ]

}

//2.2. метод: внутрь <samboForma> д.залетать 2 карточки samboForma_cart
render( ) {
// ссылка на тег <div class="samboForma">
const samboFormaDiv = document.querySelector (this.samboFormaDiv);

// FOR ( OF ): перебор данных Сырого массива ("получен" из API) (?)
for (let i of this.goods) {

 // новый экзмепляр (ОднаКарточкаТовара), где родитель class ProductItem
 const oneProductCard = new FormaSambo(i);

// В пустой массив 'productObjects'  - добавляю данные в конец [ ]" !!
 this.productObjects.push(oneProductCard);

  //вставка <div class="samboForma"> __тут КарточкаТовара___ </div>
  //html-код КарточкиТовара тянется из class FormaSambo
  //getHTMLString() - метод из class FormaSambo
  samboFormaDiv.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', oneProductCard.getHTMLString());

    }

  }

calcPriceBonus (){
const myCheck = document.querySelectorAll (this.myCheck) ;
const calcPrice = document.querySelectorAll (this.calcPrice);
const calcBonus = document.querySelectorAll (this.calcBonus);
    ///console.log(calcPrice)

    myCheck.forEach (function (e, index){
    e.addEventListener ('change' , function(e){

    let sumPrice = 0; 
    let sumBonus = 0;

    if (e.target.checked == true){
    sumPrice = e.target.dataset.price;
    sumBonus = e.target.dataset.bonus;
    } else {
    sumPrice = -(e.target.dataset.price);
    sumBonus = -(e.target.dataset.bonus);
    }

    const COUNT_CART_CHECKBOXES = 6
    const i =  Math.floor(index / COUNT_CART_CHECKBOXES)
    calcPrice[i].textContent = +calcPrice[i].textContent + +sumPrice;
    calcBonus[i].innerHTML = +calcBonus[i].innerHTML + +sumBonus;
  })

 })
} 



 }
//№2. КЛАСС, в нем есть КОНСТРУКТОР (шаблон cо свойствами): end




// №1. Класс ФормаСАМБО (карточкаТовара?) :start
class FormaSambo {
  constructor ( product   ) {
  //заголовок Карточки
   this.title = product.title || 'no_name'; // Детская , Взрослая
   this.topPrice = product.topPrice || '0'; // 1000 , 2000
   this.topBonus = product.topBonus || '0'; // 50, 100
   this.id = product.id;
   this.img = product?.img || 'no_foto.jpg';

   //вышивка (эмблема клуба)
   this.clubPrice = product.clubPrice  || '0'; // 100
   this.clubBonus = product.clubBonus || '0'; // 25

   //вышивка (эмблема самбо)
   this.samboPrice = product.samboPrice  || '0'; // 50
   this.samboBonus = product.samboBonus || '0'; // 20
       
   //вышивка (имя борца)
   this.namePrice = product.namePrice  || '0'; // 20
   this.nameBonus = product.nameBonus || '0'; // 10

   //цвет формы (черный)
   this.blackPrice = product.blackPrice  || '0'; // 10
   this.blackBonus = product.blackBonus || '0'; // 5

    //цвет формы (хаки)
   this.hakiPrice = product.hakiPrice  || '0'; // 5
   this.hakiBonus = product.hakiBonus || '0'; // 0

   }

  //отрисовка Карточек samboForma_cart "дет/взросл форма": start
  getHTMLString ( ){ return `
  <div class="samboForma_cart">

    <div class="forma_kid_name">
    <p class="name_text">${this.title}</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="formaSambo" id="${this.id}" data-price=" ${this.topPrice}" data-bonus=" ${this.topBonus}" >
    </div>
    
    <img class="forma_img" src="./img/${this.img}" alt="" >

    <div class="priceBonus">
    <p class="forma_price"> Цена: ${this.topPrice} руб*</p>
    <p class="forma_bonus"> Бонус: ${this.topBonus} баллов*</p>    
    </div>

    <!-- Блок ВЫШИВКА: start -->
    <div class="embroidery">
    <div class="embr_top optionString">Вышивка на форме</div>

    <div class="embr">
    <p class="embr_top">Эмблема клуба:</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="formaSambo" id="embr_club" data-price=" ${this.clubPrice}" data-bonus=" ${this.clubBonus}" >
    </div>

    <div class="priceBonus">
    <p class="forma_price"> Цена: ${this.clubPrice} руб*</p>
    <p class="forma_bonus"> Бонус: ${this.clubBonus} баллов*</p>
    </div>

    <div class="embr">
    <p class="embr_top">Эмблема САМБО:</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="formaSambo" id="embr_sambo" data-price="${this.samboPrice} " data-bonus=" ${this.samboBonus} " >
    </div>

    <div class="priceBonus">
    <p class="forma_price"> Цена: ${this.samboPrice} руб*</p>
    <p class="forma_bonus"> Бонус: ${this.samboBonus} баллов*</p>
    </div>

    <div class="embr">
    <p class="embr_top">Имя Фамилия:</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="formaSambo" id="embr_fio" data-price="${this.namePrice} " data-bonus=" ${this.nameBonus}" >
    </div>

    <div class="priceBonus">
    <p class="forma_price"> Цена: ${this.namePrice} руб*</p>
    <p class="forma_bonus"> Бонус: ${this.nameBonus} баллов*</p>
    </div>
    
    </div>
    <!-- Блок ВЫШИВКА: end-->


<!-- Блок ЦВЕТ ФОРМЫ: start-->
<div class="forma_color">
 <div class="color_top optionString">Опция: цвет формы</div>

    <div class="clr">
    <p class="color_top">Цвет формы Черный</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="formaSambo" id="clr_black" data-price=" ${this.blackPrice}" data-bonus="${this.blackBonus} " >
    </div>

    <div class="priceBonus">
    <p class="forma_price"> Цена: ${this.blackPrice} руб*</p>
    <p class="forma_bonus"> Бонус: ${this.blackBonus} баллов*</p>
    </div>

    <div class="clr">
    <p class="color_top">Цвет формы Хаки:</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="formaSambo" id="clr_haki" data-price=" ${this.hakiPrice}" data-bonus="${this.hakiBonus} " >
    </div>

    <div class="priceBonus">
    <p class="forma_price"> Цена: ${this.hakiPrice} руб*</p>
    <p class="forma_bonus"> Бонус: ${this.hakiBonus} баллов*</p>
    </div> 

</div>
<!-- Блок ЦВЕТ ФОРМЫ: end-->
    
    <!-- Цена за 1 покупку: start -->
    <div class="calc">

    <div class="calc_text">Итого: Стоимость и Бонусы</div>
    <p class="calc_price"></p>
    <div class="calc_bonus"></div>

    </div>
    <!-- Цена за 1 покупку: end -->


    </div>
  `
  
  }
  //отрисовка Карточек samboForma_cart "дет/взросл форма": end


}
// №1. Класс ФормаСАМБО (карточкаТовара?) :end

// скрипт стартует отсюда
const catalog = new ProductList(  );
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/*фон */

.wrapper {
  background-color: #5e5d5d;
  min-height: 100vh;
}


/*шапка: лого и "Корзина"*/

.header_top {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: rgb(149, 149, 149);
  height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


/* позиция лого: поверх*/

.header_logo {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 30px;
}


/*_____ Кнопка 'Корзина' _____*/

.btn-cart {
  margin-right: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 35px;
  align-self: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
}


/*эфф-т при наведении на кнопку*/

.btn-cart:hover {
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 13px 4px #d1d1d1;
}


/*Общая обертка: samboForma ( grid )*/

.samboForma {
  max-width: 1200px;
  /* border: 1px solid #000; */
  margin: 35px auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 22px;
  /*адаптация grid под размер окна браузера*/
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 450px));
  justify-content: center;
}


/*==== КАРТОЧКА ТОВАРА ====*/


/*Обертка Одной карточки товара*/

.samboForma_cart {
  max-width: 450px;
  border: 1px solid #2a2828;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.forma_kid_name {
  margin: 15px 0 15px 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.name_text {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
}


/*checkbox: УВЕЛИЧИТЬ окошко*/

input[type=checkbox] {
  align-self: center;
  transform: scale(1.8);
  opacity: 0.9;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*центровка фото через vw !*/

.forma_img {
  margin: 0 15%;
}


/*ценник и бонус*/

.priceBonus {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 15px 30px 15px 30px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #bfbfbf;
}


/*Блок "вышивка" (embroidery)*/

.embroidery {
  margin: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  row-gap: 8px;
}

.embr_top {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.embr {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-right: 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
}


/*Блок "цвето формы" )*/

.forma_color {
  margin: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  row-gap: 8px;
}

.color_top {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.clr {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-right: 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
}


/*цвет слов "Вышивка", "Цвет формы"*/

.optionString {
  color: #e20724;
}


/* === Блок Цена за 1 покупку ===*/

.calc {
  border: 1px solid #797979;
  margin: 0 25px 25px 25px;
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 15px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #fffec2;
}

.calc_text {
  font-weight: 600;
}


/*Приписка слов ДО и ПОСЛЕ*/

.calc_price::before {
  content: 'Цена покупки: ';
}

.calc_price::after {
  content: ' рублей ';
}

.calc_bonus::before {
  content: 'Вами заработано: ';
}

.calc_bonus::after {
  content: ' бонусов ';
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styleForma.css">
  <title>СпортФорма</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header class="header_top">
      <div class="header_logo">
        <img class="bearLogo" src="img/logo.png" alt="">
      </div>

      <button class="btn-cart" type="button">Корзина</button>
    </header>

    <main>
      <!-- samboForma (на grid): start -->
      <!-- внутрь <samboForma> д.залетать 2 карточки samboForma_cart-->
      <div class="samboForma">




      </div>
      <!-- samboForma (на grid): end -->


    </main>

  </div>

  <script src="js/samboForma.js"></script>

</body>
```